# Sinatra - undefined method `join' for #<String> - after removing Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I tried to update the Ruby version of a Sinatra website I am working on to `2.1.3`. When I tried to bundle I had some errors. Then I removed the `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install` proceeded. But when I ran the website I noticed some thing like

```
NoMethodError at /auth/login
undefined method `join' for #<String:0x000000062d3830>
```

My observations are as below.

- Downgraded to Ruby 2.1.2 - problem preserved
- Checked out the project as it was before (`Ruby 2.1.2` with the old `Gemfile.lock`) worked
- The error showed up with a `yield_content(:head)` tag.

  - Removed all `yield_content` tags
  - Error showed up rendering the slim file for the page - `slim :index, :layout => :layout, :locals => body_locals`

What could be the error? I created a diff off the state of the `Gemfile.lock` before and after: https://gist.github.com/ziyan-junaideen/fb903abbdafdc2d4a02f

Error output from the terminal: https://gist.github.com/ziyan-junaideen/54bff4f05a5a7beeedff

I thought it was some SLIM error and downgraded Slim to 2.0.3 which used to be before the bundle install, but had no luck.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As you can see in github, the problem was solved by minad. You just need to update your temple gem to latest 0.6.10 version.

Comment: @bulbform: Thanks I will have a look. Just today I re bundled a similar stack and had the same issue after removing `Gemfile.lock` and bundling. I will try to pin `temple` to `0.6.10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it by reinstalling slim and temple in versions slim: 2.0.3 and temple: 0.6.8,
it's probably in temple, 'cos downgrading slim is not enough

Answer (score 1):

I've got this error as well.

After some research I've found that it is happening because 'output buffer' for template rendering is an *instance variable* (its default name is `@_out_buf`), thus it is overwritten when each (sub)template rendering completes (because partials are being rendered in the same scope as main template)

There are a few ways to fix this without downgrading sinatra/slim/temple:

- Make default `outvar` value equals to `_out_buf` (local variable) @ lib/sinatra/base.rb#L814
- Pass an `outvar` option to `slim` method like this: `== slim :sub_template, outvar: '_out_buf'`

I've also opened an issue at sinatra's repo at github: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/939 (let's see what authors will say about this)